Trigger another property update when a collection is modified
In my C# / WPF application, I have a class with several properties:
public class VariationDefinition
{
    public int VariationsCount => Variations == null ? 0 : Variations.Count;
    public ObservableCollection<ConditionVariation> Variations { get; private set; }

    public void RegenerateVariations()
    {
        //Initializes and fills the Variations collection
        //...
    }
}

On WPF side, there are several properties that are binded to these properties, for example:
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variations}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding VariationsCount}"/>

When RegenerateVariations is called, the ListView updates immediately, indicating that binding is working properly. However, TextBlock does not update. I assume that this is because change in the Variations collection does not trigger a NotifyPropertyChanged event in the VariationsCount property.
As I understand it, it is possible to subscribe to the ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged Event (docs), but I don't know how to attach that to the VariationsCount property. I can't seem to find any examples, but I'm probably not looking for the right thing. Can you explain how to do it?

Instead of creating another variable, you can bind your UI code directly to the Count property of the ObservableCollection and it notifies the UI when the count changed as following
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variations}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Variations.Count}"/>

update
if you don't like this approach, you can notify your UI by yourself first make your class implement INotifyPropertyChanged and subscribe to the collection change event as following
public class VariationDefinition : INotifyPropertyChanged  
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public VariationDefinition()
    {
        // subscribe on collection change
        Variations.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            // notify the UI that property VariationsCount is changed
            // and UI will update the new value
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new(nameof(VariationsCount)));
        };
    }

    public int VariationsCount => Variations?.Count ?? 0;
    public ObservableCollection<ConditionVariation> Variations { get; } = new();
     
}


Thank you, for this instance it does appear to work (Variations being null doesn't seem to break it), but there may be more times when a property might need to do something more complex than just exposing a count, especially if that property is from another class and needs to observe that collection for changes.

Thank you, this is much better, but what if the property that needs to subscribe to CollectionChanged is from another class that VariationDefinition shouldn't be aware of? Is it possible to subscribe to that event externally somehow, or expose a public function in VariationDefinition that enables late subscription?

VariationDefinition is care about her property and changes in it and notify the outside world through PropertyChanged event .... in other meaning if any code outside VariationDefinition care about the Property changed in VariationDefinition he can subscribe to the PropertyChanged event which come from INotifyPropertyChanged interface ... UI subscribe to this event automatically

I recommend you read this article on Responding to changes will give you more information about INotifyPropertyChanged

Binding to the ObservableCollection.Count property, as initially suggested, is the better soiution.

@BionicCode I have same opinion too

@JustinasRubinovas if this solution doesn't solve your problem, update the question and add more information on what is the exact scenario you try to solve

Just be aware that replacing an element in the collection would not change its Count, so I'd say attaching a CollectionChanged handler is what you should generally do in order to update dependent properties. Count is only a simple special case.

Thank you very much. Your answer works for the scenario I posted, and I tested your other suggestions - they work as well. @Clemens, thank you for the advice as well, this is something I definitely need to consider.
